# jQuery fancybox popup issue with fullcalendar event click with MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery fullcalendar and jQuery fancybox plugins in my current MVC project, My Issue is that, I want to open fancybox popup on my calendar event click, I able to open the popup by following snippet.

```
function openFancybox(object)
    {
        $.fancybox({
                    transitionIn: 'elastic',
                    transitionOut: 'elastic',
                    speedIn: 600,
                    speedOut: 200,
                    overlayShow: true,
                    type: 'inline',
                    content: '#dialogPopup',
                    onComplete: function () {
                    }
                });
                return false;
    }
```

Here, openFancybox is function that called when somone click on calendar event.
Now, my issue is that popup comes blank on single click, but when, I again click it opens, Also, I lost all jQuery bindings that, I used for the other controls on the view i.e Dropdown change events, button click events etc.

Following is my snippet for popup div and ajax to fill PartialView data in div

```
<div id="dialogPopup" class="add-job-block">
</div>


$.get("/Events/LoadData", { id: object.id }, function (data) {
                if (data != undefined && data != "") {
                    $("#dialogPopup").html("");
                    $("#dialogPopup").html(data);
                    //$.uniform.restore();
                    //$(".styled, input:radio, input:checkbox, .dataTables_length select").not('.no-uniform').uniform();
                }
            });
```

I have also used jQuery uniform plugin for styling the dropdown and other input controls.
The complete function snippet is as follows,

```
function openFancybox()
{
           $.get("/Events/LoadData", { id: object.id }, function (data) {
                    if (data != undefined && data != "") {
                        $("#dialogPopup").html("");
                        $("#dialogPopup").html(data);
                        //$.uniform.restore();
                        //$(".styled, input:radio, input:checkbox, .dataTables_length select").not('.no-uniform').uniform();
                    }
                });


             $.fancybox({            
                        transitionIn: 'elastic',
                        transitionOut: 'elastic',
                        speedIn: 600,
                        speedOut: 200,
                        overlayShow: true,
                        type: 'inline',
                        content: '#dialogPopup',
                        onComplete: function () {
                        }
                    });
                    return false;


}
```

I am calling function from calendar plugin call i.e.

```
 var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceDay,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        eventClick: updateEvent,
        ignoreTimezone: true,
        disableResizing: false,
        disableDragging: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: selectDate,
        editable: true,
        resources: "/Calendar/EventsResourceList",
        events: "/Calendar/EventsList",
        eventResize: eventResizedCompleted,
        eventDrop: eventDragCompleted,
        eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
            Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function () {
                return this.getMonth() +
            "/" + this.getDate() +
            "/" + this.getFullYear();
            }
            var eventDate = new Date(event.start);
            var todaysDate = new Date();
            if (todaysDate.formatMMDDYYYY() === eventDate.formatMMDDYYYY()) {
                setInterval(function () {
                    element.fadeOut(500).delay(300).fadeIn(400);
                }, 2000);
            }

        }
    }); 

function updateEvent(event, element) {
   openFancybox({ id: event.id, jobid: event.JobID });
}
```

So, My issue is Popup comes on 2 clicks, also, I lost all jQuery bindings from controls, so anyone has any suggestion or tweak or solution or gone through this problem can be helpful to me.

Comment: where u calling openFancybox() in html ? and why return false ?

Comment: Hi Neha, I have updated the question and added calling part, kindly check it once..

Comment: I am just guessing and its hard to test it if possible make fiddle. I think remove return false (as its use to prevent default action) and call the js $('#dialogPopup').fancybox({...}); its better to direct attach the element.